# Residue Theorem: Evaluate the integral $\int_\pi^{3\pi} \frac {dx}{5\cos x+13}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration, laurent-series

Evaluate the integral using the Residue Theorem. $$\int_\pi^{3\pi} \frac {dx}{5\cos x+13}$$

---

Residue Theorem makes my head hurt. I have a lot of trouble with Laurent series in the first place. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Take advantage that $\cos$ is periodic every $2\pi$ and that $\cos(-x)=\cos(+x)$.

Comment: to generalize SimplyBeautifulArt's comment: As a general rule of thumb, when investigating integrals (or really *any* mathematical object) start by looking for symmetries. Use symmetry to your advantage, and work alongside symmetry... you will often be rewarded.

Comment: Also, to make the symmetry in this case a bit more transparent, note that the integral is the same over the intervals $[\pi,3\pi]$, $[-\pi, \pi]$ and also $[0,2\pi]$. Do you see any of these that have nice parameterizations that relate heavily to the Cosine (and Sine) functions?

Comment: Finally, worth noting that those constants are somewhat irrelevant. It might give you some clarity to look at the antiderivative: $$\int \frac{1}{a\cos(x)+b}\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{(b-a) \tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Lol, the tags imply this is to be done with complex analysis, not anti-derivatives :P

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I didn't mean to imply that the OP ought to SOLVE this using the antiderivative - I provided it to provide insight. Note the symmetries involved between $a$ and $b$ in the antiderivative, including the tangent and its (hyperbolic) inverse, as well as the appearance of $\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$ twice. Expanding on this second symmetry, note that **all** instances of $a$ and $b$ involve subtracting one from the other, implying that the two constants are closely tied in calculations.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Of course, simply noting these symmetries is not nearly enough to solve it using complex analysis, which is why I put these in the comments - nevertheless, 1) Noting such symmetries can aid in calculations and finding patterns, and 2) I find such symmetries beautiful, and worth observing/noting simply for their own merit. I mean, come on... look at how beautiful that antiderivative is. If nothing else, it makes me question why there is a $-2$ out front! (this, btw, means ought to note that observing when symmetries break (such as the presence of the $-2$) is also important)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Aw man, you said simply and beautiful in that comment, but you forgot the art!  >_>

Comment: Final note to the OP: Once you adjust the domain of integration and parameterize, I would update your post with this. This will show effort, and is a good step towards getting an answer!

Answer (score 5):

The approach to evaluating this integral using contour integration is classical.  It begins with the substitution $z=e^{i x}$, which implies $dx=\frac{1}{iz}\,dz$.  The domain of integration transforms from $x\in [\pi,3\pi]$ to an integral on the unit circle $|z|=1$.

Proceeding as discussed, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_\pi^{3\pi}\frac{1}{5\cos(x)+13}\,dx&=\oint_{|z|=1}\left(\frac{1}{5\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)+13}\right)\,\frac{1}{iz}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac2i \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{5z^2+26z+5}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac2i \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{(5z+1)(z+5)}\,dz\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac2i\right)\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(5z+1)(z+5)},z=-1/5\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice explanation and derivation. Can be used as prototype for many similar integrals. (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thank you Markus!  Much appreciated.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

By exploiting symmetry *and* the residue theorem such integral is pretty simple to tackle.
Symmetry first:
$$ \int_{\pi}^{3\pi}\frac{dx}{5\cos x+13}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{13+5\cos(x)} = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{13+5\cos x}\\ = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{26}{13^2-5^2\cos^2 x}\stackrel{x\mapsto \arctan t}{=} 54\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{13^2(1+t^2)-5^2} $$
and the problem boils down to computing:

$$ 26\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{12^2+13^2 t^2} = 26\cdot(2\pi i)\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{12^2 + 13^2 t^2},t=\frac{12}{13}i\right)$$
or:
$$ 26\cdot(2\pi i)\cdot\left(-\frac{i}{312}\right) = \frac{54 \pi}{312} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{6}}.$$